# Git repository within docker python image

Tags: python, git, docker

I have a dockerfile, where my image is python:3.7-alpine.

In my project, I use a git repository I need to download.
Is there any way to do that ?

My Dockerfile :

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine

ENV DOCKER_APP True

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . app/

WORKDIR app/

ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "main.py"]
```

my requirements :

```
certifi==2020.6.20
requests==2.24.0
urllib3==1.25.10
git+https://github.com/XXX/YYY
```

Thank

Comment: I used slim-buster image instead of alpine. 
And I run "RUN apt-get update; apt-get install-y git" 
Hope it will help you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

add the following to your dockerfile

```
RUN apk update
RUN apk add git
```